# check if value appears within list created from key() step in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, gremlinjs

I have a vertex that has a 'title' property. I have other vertices that have outgoing edges that have multiple properties. I'm trying to find vertices that have outgoing edges where the 'title' property value is a property key on the edge.

For example Vertex A has property {'title': ['lebron']} and Edge B has property
{'lebron': 'basketball'}.

This is the example graph I have:

```
g.addV('person').property(id, 'bob')
g.addV('person').property(id, 'alice').addE().to(__.V('bob')).property('lebron', 'basketball')
g.addV('player').property('title', 'lebron').addE().from(__.V('bob'))
```

This is the query I currently came up with that isn't working:

```
   g
    .V('alice')
    .outE()
    .as('b')
    .otherV()
    .hasId('bob')
    .as('c')
    .select('b')
    .properties()
    .key()
    .fold()
    .as('k')
    .select('c')
    .outE()
    .otherV()
    .has('title', within('k')))
    .valueMap('title')
    .toList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
g
.V('alice')
.outE()
.as('b')
.otherV()
.hasId('bob')
.as('c')
.select('b')
.aggregate('keys').by(properties().key())
.select('c')
.out()
.where(values().where(within('keys')))
.valueMap('title')
.toList()
```

Comment: You almost got it! I modified it slightly to this and it worked, thank you very much:

Instead of `.aggregate('keys').by(properties().key())` I used, `.properties().key().aggregate('keys')`

Answer (score 1):

Here's likely a more "Gremlin-othic" approach.  Gremlin is meant to be an imperative query language, so the best approach is to try to "find-then-filter".  Instead of using as() and select() statements and jumping around everywhere, it is better to make your path/traversal, label things along the way, and then filter at the very end.

```
g.V('alice').outE('edge').as('b').inV().hasId('bob').out().
    where(eq('b')).
        by(values('title')).
        by(properties().key()).
    valueMap()
```

This approach uses the `where()-by()` pattern, which in this case takes two `by()` modulators.  The first modulating the values coming into the `where()` statement (the vertices found by the last `out()`) and the second `by()` modulates what is inside of the `where()` statement (the property keys of the edge).

More on `where()-by()` here:  https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#whereby

Comment: I'm using aws-neptune and unfortunately inV() doesn't work there.

Comment: Tried it with otherV and it didn;t work for me

Comment: inV() should work on Neptune.  The query above ran on a Neptune cluster.  What programming language/Gremlin library are you using?

Comment: You're correct I just tried it again and it works fine. If I ever come across an error with it I'll let you know, thanks!

Comment: This is the query that I tried on my neptune cluster with gremlin js v3.6.0 and it's returning a null value:

`g?.V('alice').outE('edge').as('b').inV().hasId('bob').out().where(P.eq('b')).by(__.values('title')).by(__.properties().key()).valueMap().next();`

Comment: Likely that you need to change the 'edge' label of the outE() to fit whatever label you're using for edges.  Also note, the latest version of Neptune only supports up to version 3.5.2 of TinkerPop/Gremlin.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I changed the 'edge' tag but it still yields a null value.